# Rails 3 MimeType fallback for :mobile mime type back to standard html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mobile

I am running my app locally in safari and testing a mobile user agent by using Safari switcher in the dev menu.  But I returns the following error:

```
Template is missing

    Missing template pages/home, application/home with {:handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :coffee], :formats=>[:mobile], :locale=>[:en, :en]}. Searched in: * "/Users/tjs/Sites/bob/app/views" * "/Users/tjs/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/devise-1.4.5/app/views"
```

I understand this to mean i don't have a mobile layout.  Is there a way to simply use the standard view files instead of making new ones for each view?  Either fallback the mimetype to html or over ride it across my whole app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your application_controller.rb:

```
before_filter :determine_format

def determine_format
  request.format = :html if request.format == :mobile
end
```

All your :mobile format requests will now become :html requests.